# Filter on multiple columns in Spark Dataframe based API

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|     id1|    id2|                body|         created_at|
+--------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|1       |      4|....................|2017-10-01 00:00:05|
|2       |      3|....................|2017-10-01 00:00:05|
|3       |      2|....................|2017-10-01 00:00:05|
|4       |      1|....................|2017-10-01 00:00:05|
+--------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to filter the table using both `id1` and `id2`. For example get rows where `id1=1, id2=4` and `id1=2, id2=3`.

Currently, I'm using loop to generate a giant query string for `df.filter()`, i.e. `((id1 = 1) and (id2 = 4)) or ((id1 = 2) and (id2 = 3))`. Just wondering if there is a more properly way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a helper DF (table):

**tmp:**

```
+--------+-------+
|     id1|    id2|
+--------+-------+
|1       |      4|
|2       |      3|
+--------+-------+
```

and then join them:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tab a
JOIN tmp b
  ON (a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2)
```

where `tab` is your original DF, registered as a table

Comment: Thanks MaxU, how is the performance of this approach? I tried it to select 2 rows from 437 rows, which took 8.11s and my original approach took 0.03s.

Comment: I guess this approach will be slower, but it doesn't depend on number of rows in the `tmp` table.Your approach may fail if the condition string will be too long...